# Python AttributeError: Object has no attribute in Unittest

Tags: python, class, methods, python-unittest

I have 2 scripts, 1st is All_Methods, and another is All_Testcases, as I am using unittest framework, so here we go.

All_Methods is like:

```
class All_Services():
    def abc(self):
        x =1

    def bca(self):
        print "My Name is Taimoor"
        self.abc()

    def cba(self):
        self.bca()
```

and on another script which is All_TestCases is like this:

```
from All_Methods import All_Services as service

    class All_TestCases(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_1_running_method(self)
            service.cba(self)
```

Exception showing is:

```
AttributeError: 'All_TestCases' object has no attribute 'bca'
```

Kindly someone tell me, what I am missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have variable indentation width, you should fix that.

Comment: You should try to do minimal example where you can show use the same problem. You don't need unittest and you don't need any code in the methods to trigger this problem.

Comment: Actually This is the requirement, which is requird from us.

Comment: What I mean is that you can reproduce the problem with simpler code to understand and learn how to fix the problem.

Comment: and its not variable indentation issue, else it would have send me indentationerror.

Comment: Updated the indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using classes in the usual way when you pass in self to methods that you call on the class. Common is to call the methods on instances of the class and getting the self argument implicitly.

When you call `Method.running_query_Athena(self)` self is an instance of `All_TestCases` which does not have the method `connecting_Athena`.

Did you mean for `All_TestCases` to derive from `All_Methods`?

Why is `All_Methods` a class at all?

Comment: Using All_Methods as a class is just a generic example. and I am trying to do what you have mentioned, but all in vein.,

Answer (score 1):

1. Use proper indentation since python is solely based on the basis of how the code is indented.
2. Please, Please use proper naming conventions; as advised under [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
3. You're trying to access an instance method without an instance.

Try the following:

```
class MyClass:
    def my_instance_method(self):
        return True

    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls):
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def my_static_method():
        return True
```

This won't work:

```
>> MyClass.my_instance_method()
TypeError: my_instance_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

but these will since they are not bound to a class instance being created.

```
MyClass.my_class_method()
MyClass.my_static_method()
```

An instance method requires that you instantiate the Class; meaning you use:

```
MyClass().my_instance_method()
```

Since you seem to want to set `response_id` on the class instance; using the `self` argument which denotes the class instance to get the `response_id`. - I suggest that you use an instance method and instantiate the class as shown above (note the `()` after the class name)

Kindly do fix your formatting in the question.

Comment: While calling the method with creating an object within a script is working, but when I am using the same thing on other script on other class, its not working att all.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the entire code? (removing any sensitive data)

Comment: My guess is that you're misusing `self` in the testcases; I think you might be over complicating your life a tiny bit, try using this https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html - it might help. Also: `from All_Methods import All_Methods as Method` change this to something more unique. - The question itself is quite difficult to read, if you want update it, and let me know, I'll try to help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong with the code in the example, but putting that aside.

The error is caused by passing an instance of `class A` as the `self` argument to a (non-static) method of `class B`.
Python will attempt to call this method on the instance of `class A`, resulting in the missing attribute error.

Here is a simplified example of the problem:

```
class A:
    def is_ham(self):
        # Python secretly does `self.is_ham()` here, 
        # because `self` is the current instance of Class A. 
        # Unless you explicitly pass `self` when calling the method.
        return True


class B:
    def is_it_ham(self):
        # Note, `self` is an instance of class B here.
        return A.is_ham(self)


spam = B()
spam.is_it_ham()
```